# How can I diagnose if a failing trackpad has a hardware or software cause?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad, software

My trackpad is misbehaving, it randomly interprets clicks as swipes and the cursor jumps around or lags on the screen.

How can I find out if this is a hardware or software issue?

I'm on a MacBook Pro 5,3 with OS X 10.11.6.
Using a bluetooth mouse (Logitech MX Master) I see none of these issues.

### Steps taken

- Restart - solves the problem for a few minutes, but symptoms return
- Different user - same as restart
- Apple Hardware Test - pressed <kbd>D</kbd> during startup, but the hardware test did not start and the machine started in normal mode.